# Using awk printf to urldecode text

Tags: awk, printf, urldecode, busybox

I'm using `awk` to urldecode some text.

If I code the string into the `printf` statement like `printf "%s", "\x3D"` it correctly outputs `=`. The same if I have the whole escaped string as a variable.

However, if I only have the `3D`, how can I append the `\x` so `printf` will print the `=` and not `\x3D`?

I'm using `busybox awk 1.4.2` and the `ash` shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ash and Perl isn't available, I'm assuming that you may not have `gawk`.

For me, using `gawk` or **busybox awk**, your second example works the same as the first (I get "=" from both) unless I use the `--posix` option (in which case I get "x3D" for *both*).

If I use `--non-decimal-data` or `--traditional` with `gawk` I get "=".

What version of AWK are you using (`awk`, `nawk`, `gawk`, busybox - and version number)?

**Edit:**

You can coerce the variable's string value into a numeric one by adding zero:

```
~/busybox/awk 'BEGIN { string="3D"; pre="0x"; hex=pre string; printf "%c", hex+0}'
```

Comment: You'r right, it does work.  I asked the wrong question - I'll amend it. (I'm using busybox awk, version 1.4.2)

Comment: Took me quite awhile to realize this one-liner is for __one__ variable only, no whole urlencoded string (e. g. a web address filled up with `%20` and `%3F` stuff)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you do this in awk, but it's trivial in perl:

```
echo "http://example.com/?q=foo%3Dbar" | 
    perl -pe 's/\+/ /g; s/%([0-9a-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eig'
```

Comment: Thanks, but perl isn't available.

Comment: @zwol This only works on Perl 5 if you escape the `+` with a backslash! BTW, works fine for me with sample URLs without the `s/\+/ /g` part at all! The second regex alone will do the trick already.

Comment: @syntaxerror You're quite right about the `+` needing to be escaped, don't know how I missed that.  I think the `?q=phrase+separated+by+plus+signs` notation has gotten less common since I wrote this but it's still part of the [spec for application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) escaping of form submissions.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot about those form submissions. However, since my main aim is fixing "garbled" download links, the most important thing is to get rid of all this `%20`, `%3D` and `%3F` (et al) stuff in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

GNU awk

```perl
#!/usr/bin/awk -fn
@include "ord"
BEGIN {
  RS = "%.."
}
{
  printf RT ? $0 chr("0x" substr(RT, 2)) : $0
}
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -niord '{printf RT?$0chr("0x"substr(RT,2)):$0}' RS=%..
```

[Decoding URL encoding (percent encoding)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159253/#159373)

Comment: This garbles e.g. UTF-8-encoded non-ASCII characters

Answer (score 1):

This relies on gnu awk's extension of the split function, but this works:

```
gawk '{ numElems = split($0, arr, /%../, seps);
        outStr = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= numElems - 1; i++) {
            outStr = outStr arr[i]
            outStr = outStr sprintf("%c", strtonum("0x" substr(seps[i],2)))
        }
        outStr = outStr arr[i]
        print outStr
      }'
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I'm aware this is an old question, but none of the answers worked for me (restricted to busybox awk)

Two options. To parse stdin:

```
awk '{for (y=0;y<127;y++) if (y!=37) gsub(sprintf("%%%02x|%%%02X",y,y), y==38 ? "\\&" : sprintf("%c", y));gsub(/%25/, "%");print}'
```

To take a command line parameter:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (y=0;y<127;y++) if (y!=37) gsub(sprintf("%%%02x|%%%02X",y,y), y==38 ? "\\&" : sprintf("%c", y), ARGV[1]);gsub(/%25/, "%", ARGV[1]);print ARGV[1]}' parameter
```

Have to do %25 last because otherwise strings like %253D get double-parsed, which shouldn't happen.

The inline check for y==38 is because gsub treats & as a special character unless you backslash it.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the fastest of them all by a large margin and it doesn't need gawk:

```
#!/usr/bin/mawk -f

function decode_url(url,            dec, tmp, pre, mid, rep) {
    tmp = url
    while (match(tmp, /\%[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]/)) {
        pre = substr(tmp, 1, RSTART - 1)
        mid = substr(tmp, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 1)
        rep = sprintf("%c", ("0x" mid) + 0)
        dec = dec pre rep
        tmp = substr(tmp, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    return dec tmp
}

{
    print decode_url($0)
}
```

Save it as `decode_url.awk` and use it like you normally would. E.g:

```
$ ./decode_url.awk <<< 'Hello%2C%20world%20%21'
Hello, world !
```

But if you want an even faster version:

```
#!/usr/bin/mawk -f

function gen_url_decode_array(      i, n, c) {
    delete decodeArray
    for (i = 32; i < 64; ++i) {
        c = sprintf("%c", i)
        n = sprintf("%%%02X", i)
        decodeArray[n] = c
        decodeArray[tolower(n)] = c
    }
}

function decode_url(url,            dec, tmp, pre, mid, rep) {
    tmp = url
    while (match(tmp, /\%[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]/)) {
        pre = substr(tmp, 1, RSTART - 1)
        mid = substr(tmp, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        rep = decodeArray[mid]
        dec = dec pre rep
        tmp = substr(tmp, RSTART + RLENGTH)
    }
    return dec tmp
}

BEGIN {
    gen_url_decode_array()
}

{
    print decode_url($0)
}
```

Other interpreters than `mawk` should have no problem with them.